# C# Winform - My panel background color keeps disappearing when i place it over other's right - bottom edge

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

Here is before I place it over another panel:

[image]

And here is after i place it over other panel:
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example for us to understand what you do, otherwise you can't expect a satisfying answer here on so. THX

Comment: @StephanT. This only drag and drop toolbox in VS, no code involve yet.

Answer (score 0):

Select your panel and click 'Bring to Front' button like in screen shot
https://prnt.sc/lurljw

You should draw new panel over place where it should be, it will work. Because when you draw panel on other panel it becomes it's child and when you move child to right or bottom side it try to stay inside parent.